# Is there a recomended method for symbolizing inland lakes, streams and rivers in a topographic map?

Tags: cartography, symbology

I produce a lot of maps with inland lakes, rivers and streams overlaid over a dem surface symbolized with a color graduation (green for lows and brown for higher elevations) I also use a semi-transparent shaded relief to enhance the terrain. I have a standard blue color I often used for both lakes and streams but I noticed that **sometimes** the hydrology does not stand out enough. I experimented with outline for the lakes and with dark and light blues but nothing seems to work for every map.

Can someone recommend a good color/method for symbolizing lakes/streams/rivers?

Is there a generally accepted standard theme for symbolizing lakes/streams/rivers? (Ontario, Canada)

Comment: Are these maps for the web or print maps?

Comment: print maps. Very detailed 1:20,000 (m) and larger

Answer (score 4):

[Are there any international standards for map symbology?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3046/are-there-any-international-standards-for-map-symbology)

That question has good suggestions for map symbols.  The accepted answer links to [this document on hydrography](http://inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/documents/Data_Specifications/INSPIRE_DataSpecification_HY_v3.0.1.pdf).

Comment: thanks. I've skimmed trough this document before. Northwestern Ontario in Canada has a very unique hydrology and topography and although I am using similar symbology as the European standard it also does not work well with the underlying surface color ramp. Natural Resources Canada has a similar set of standards but it does not work well with the complex surface I need to display in my maps. (blue color blends visually with some surface colors)

Answer (score 3):

- At large scales use contours. These can continue within lakes using a dark blue shade.
- Try adjusting the transparency based on the size of the lake.  A very small feature does not need to be as transparent as a very large feature.
- Use a slightly lighter color for the outline of the transparency.  It is important to remember that the color you ultimately get from a transparency is not what you actually set. Choose an outline that contrasts to the average mix post-transparency rather than the color you actually set.
- Try adjusting the shade based on the depth, similar to the [Crater Lake example at ESRI](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=maps.craterLake)

Answer (score 2):

If the greens and browns are dark, then have you tried white? I've certainly seen that before. Otherwise perhaps someone on [cartotalk.com](http://www.cartotalk.com) could help?