# Symbology or Styles

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-9.3, symbology

Anyone know where to find me some more symbology or styles that I can use for my ArcMap 9.3.1 ?

I have lots of mxd files on my computer and how do I apply all of my symbology or styles turn on ? Every time I open my mxd files I have to turn on each in the Style Reference dialog box because they are not enable check.

Comment: is there a particular new style or symbol that you are looking for. Also, are you looking to set a global style setting for all your mxd's?

Comment: artwork  - no particular style or symbol. Yes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ESRI Mapping Center](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=arcgisResources.gateway) has a downloadable styles section, at least some of which work in 9.3, particularly those which are fonts. For those that aren't fonts it's not generally known that `.style` are simply ms-access `.mdb` files with another name. So you might be able to backport the v10 styles to v9 with a little bit of Access hackery.

Also [Are there any international standards for map symbology?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3046/are-there-any-international-standards-for-map-symbology) has some links to pages with downloadable symbol sets.

Answer (score 3):

One way so far that I've found to set a global style is to add those symbols that you use frequently to your defaut user style, e.g.

C:\Documents and Settings\PROBERT\Application Data\ESRI\ArcMap\PROBERT.style

If you open a blank ArcMap and goto Tools(menu)>Styles>Style Manager, highlight your user style and you can then right click over Fill Symbolos, Line Symbols, or Marker Symbols and select New>Marker Style...  Through the various dialogs you can then source existing symbology through other styles that you use often.  The new symbols you add to your user style should be active for all your saved mxd projects.

Comment: this is the best method - been doing it for years now.