# Are there any icons for GIS mapping?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-platform, icon

I am trying to find alternative symbology for GIS maps and web apps I occasionally produce. Esri has done a great job collecting and categorizing thousands of symbols, markers, line and polygon styles. For instance, here one can find [all 9.3 symbology available in ArcGIS](http://downloads2.esri.com/MappingCenter2007/arcGISResources/more/ArcGIS_v93_Styles.PDF). They are available as [individual categories](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/product-announcements/view/productid/79/metaid/854) here, too. I have also seen a great resource page on [Esri Mapping Center](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=arcgisResources.gateway) with lots of additional styles. Quite many links on symbology standards [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3046/are-there-any-international-standards-for-map-symbology), too.

I am however looking for any good resources with symbology that can be not necessary related to mapping/physical geography, but rather something that describes world around us. The one I liked really much is available [here](http://www.webhostinghub.com/glyphs/), which is part of this [library](http://icomoon.io/app/#library). I fully understand that there are plenty of resources like [mapicons](http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/category/markers/). Any other website worth visiting when looking for icons for map symbols?

Comment: Surprised I missed this post. That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [Maki Icon Project](http://www.mapbox.com/maki/), its [GitHub project page](https://github.com/mapbox/maki) also has [ArcGIS `.style` and `.serverstyle` files](https://github.com/mapbox/maki/tree/gh-pages/ArcGIS).